# Python sort list of dictionary by float values

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

The following is my list

```
List_data = [{'cases_covers': 0.1625}, {'headphone': 0.1988}, {'laptop': 0.2271}, {'mobile': 0.2501}, {'perfume': 0.4981}, {'shoe': 0.1896}, {'sunglass': 0.1693}]
```

Final answer should be like this:

```
[{'perfume': 0.4981}, {'mobile': 0.2501}, {'laptop': 0.2271}, {'headphone': 0.1988},{'shoe': 0.1896}, {'sunglass': 0.1693},{'cases_covers': 0.1625}]
```

i want them to be sorted based on the value of the key in descending order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Comment: "i want them to be sorted based on the value of the key in descending order" actually, in your example, `"perfume", "mobile", "laptop"` are the **keys** and `0.4981, 0.2501` are the **values**, according to the standard vocabulary for dictionaries in python.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of **values** of a dictionary `d` with `d.values()`. Since your dictionaries have only one entry each, these lists will be singletons. You can use these singleton-lists to sort `List_data` by supplying a keyword argument to the `sort` function.

Please note that in your example, `"perfume", "mobile", "laptop"` are the **keys** and `0.4981, 0.2501` are the **values**, according to the standard vocabulary for dictionaries in python.

```py
List_data = [{'cases_covers': 0.1625}, {'headphone': 0.1988}, {'laptop': 0.2271}, {'mobile': 0.2501}, {'perfume': 0.4981}, {'shoe': 0.1896}, {'sunglass': 0.1693}]
List_data.sort(key=lambda d: list(d.values()), reverse=True)
print(List_data)
```

Output:

```
[{'perfume': 0.4981}, {'mobile': 0.2501}, {'laptop': 0.2271}, {'headphone': 0.1988}, {'shoe': 0.1896}, {'sunglass': 0.1693}, {'cases_covers': 0.1625}]
```

### Important remark

The previous piece of code was answering your question literally, without knowledge of the context in which you are trying to sort this list of dictionaries.

I am under the impression that your use of lists and dictionaries is not optimal. Of course, without knowledge of the context, I am only guessing. But perhaps using only one dictionary would better suit your needs:

```py
dictionary_data = {'cases_covers': 0.1625, 'headphone': 0.1988, 'laptop': 0.2271, 'mobile': 0.2501, 'perfume': 0.4981, 'shoe': 0.1896, 'sunglass': 0.1693}
list_data = sorted(dictionary_data.items(), key=lambda it: it[1], reverse=True)
print(list_data)
```

Output:

```
[('perfume', 0.4981), ('mobile', 0.2501), ('laptop', 0.2271), ('headphone', 0.1988), ('shoe', 0.1896), ('sunglass', 0.1693), ('cases_covers', 0.1625)]
```